# ksql, select on table not show anything

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I created a source topic subscriber have input message like this:

```
{
  "ip_router": "",
  "ip_lan": "",
  "isdn": "2046573688",
  "end_datetime": "",
  "shop_code": "1000405100",
  "reg_type_id": "5131615",
  "contract_id": "",
  "update_datetime": "20170801171355",
  "project": "",
  "telecom_service_id": "2",
  "local_speed": "",
  "password": "",
  "price_plan": "",
  "vip": "",
  "local_price_plan": "",
  "sub_id": "1083168000",
  "sta_datetime": "20090511152847",
  "update_number_1": "1",
  "act_status": "000",
  "network_class": "",
  "limit_usage": "",
  "num_reset_zone": "",
  "deposit": "",
  "create_user": "TUDV_POPBGG",
  "num_of_computer": "",
  "cust_id": "10922428129",
  "status": "2",
  "active_datetime": "20090511152102",
  "ip_view": "",
  "channel_type_id": "",
  "ip_wan": "",
  "imsi": "452049760887694",
  "infrastructure_type": "",
  "product_code": "HPN03",
  "expire_datetime": "",
  "speed": "",
  "private_ip": "",
  "update_user": "MIGRATE",
  "ip_static": "",
  "vlan": "",
  "sub_type": "",
  "create_datetime": "20090511152102",
  "is_info_completed": "1",
  "pay_type": "2",
  "up_link": "",
  "promotion_code": "",
  "technology": "",
  "offer_id": "400001035",
  "dev_staff_id": "",
  "account_id": "",
  "deploy_accept_date": "",
  "serial": "8984049767000887694",
  "group_id": "",
  "ip_gateway": "",
  "first_connect": "",
  "org_product_code": "MIGRATE",
  "start_money": "100000",
  "keep_alive": "",
  "account": ""
}
```

And then I created a stream and a table on it:

```
CREATE STREAM str_subscriber_json (sub_id VARCHAR,contract_id VARCHAR,cust_id VARCHAR,account_id VARCHAR,telecom_service_id VARCHAR,isdn VARCHAR,imsi VARCHAR,serial VARCHAR,status VARCHAR,product_code VARCHAR,offer_id VARCHAR,act_status VARCHAR,sta_datetime BIGINT,active_datetime BIGINT,sub_type VARCHAR,end_datetime BIGINT,expire_datetime BIGINT,shop_code VARCHAR,dev_staff_id VARCHAR,promotion_code VARCHAR,vip VARCHAR,account VARCHAR,create_datetime BIGINT,create_user VARCHAR,update_datetime BIGINT,update_user VARCHAR,deposit VARCHAR,limit_usage VARCHAR,password VARCHAR,org_product_code VARCHAR,num_reset_zone VARCHAR,start_money VARCHAR,is_info_completed VARCHAR,channel_type_id VARCHAR,first_connect VARCHAR,speed VARCHAR,keep_alive VARCHAR,price_plan VARCHAR,local_price_plan VARCHAR,project VARCHAR,local_speed VARCHAR,technology VARCHAR,network_class VARCHAR,infrastructure_type VARCHAR,deploy_accept_date BIGINT,group_id VARCHAR,ip_static VARCHAR,ip_view VARCHAR,ip_lan VARCHAR,ip_wan VARCHAR,ip_gateway VARCHAR,ip_router VARCHAR,num_of_computer VARCHAR,vlan VARCHAR,up_link VARCHAR,private_ip VARCHAR,pay_type VARCHAR,update_number_1 VARCHAR,reg_type_id VARCHAR,type VARCHAR,update_number VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='subscriber', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');

CREATE TABLE tbl_subscriber_json (sub_id VARCHAR,contract_id VARCHAR,cust_id VARCHAR,account_id VARCHAR,telecom_service_id VARCHAR,isdn VARCHAR,imsi VARCHAR,serial VARCHAR,status VARCHAR,product_code VARCHAR,offer_id VARCHAR,act_status VARCHAR,sta_datetime BIGINT,active_datetime BIGINT,sub_type VARCHAR,end_datetime BIGINT,expire_datetime BIGINT,shop_code VARCHAR,dev_staff_id VARCHAR,promotion_code VARCHAR,vip VARCHAR,account VARCHAR,create_datetime BIGINT,create_user VARCHAR,update_datetime BIGINT,update_user VARCHAR,deposit VARCHAR,limit_usage VARCHAR,password VARCHAR,org_product_code VARCHAR,num_reset_zone VARCHAR,start_money VARCHAR,is_info_completed VARCHAR,channel_type_id VARCHAR,first_connect VARCHAR,speed VARCHAR,keep_alive VARCHAR,price_plan VARCHAR,local_price_plan VARCHAR,project VARCHAR,local_speed VARCHAR,technology VARCHAR,network_class VARCHAR,infrastructure_type VARCHAR,deploy_accept_date BIGINT,group_id VARCHAR,ip_static VARCHAR,ip_view VARCHAR,ip_lan VARCHAR,ip_wan VARCHAR,ip_gateway VARCHAR,ip_router VARCHAR,num_of_computer VARCHAR,vlan VARCHAR,up_link VARCHAR,private_ip VARCHAR,pay_type VARCHAR,update_number_1 VARCHAR,reg_type_id VARCHAR,type VARCHAR,update_number VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='subscriber', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', KEY = 'sub_id' );
```

I tried to use ksql for test:

```
SELECT * FROM str_subscriber_json;
```

*(print result when I put new json to subscriber topic)*

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriber_json;
```

*(didn’t show any thing when I put new json to subscriber topic)*

So please clarify for me what wrong for this case?

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Summary

Your messages need to be keyed. If you don't have a message key then the semantics of a TABLE don't make any sense (since you can't show the value for a key, if there is no key).

I've reproduced your example, using [`kafkacat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/) to produce messages with and without a key.

### Test 1 - no key

#### Produce test message

```
$ echo '{ "ip_router": "", "ip_lan": "", "isdn": "2046573688", "end_datetime": "", "shop_code": "1000405100", "reg_type_id": "5131615", "contract_id": "", "update_datetime": "20170801171355", "project": "", "telecom_service_id": "2", "local_speed": "", "password": "", "price_plan": "", "vip": "", "local_price_plan": "", "sub_id": "1083168000", "sta_datetime": "20090511152847", "update_number_1": "1", "act_status": "000", "network_class": "", "limit_usage": "", "num_reset_zone": "", "deposit": "", "create_user": "TUDV_POPBGG", "num_of_computer": "", "cust_id": "10922428129", "status": "2", "active_datetime": "20090511152102", "ip_view": "", "channel_type_id": "", "ip_wan": "", "imsi": "452049760887694", "infrastructure_type": "", "product_code": "HPN03", "expire_datetime": "", "speed": "", "private_ip": "", "update_user": "MIGRATE", "ip_static": "", "vlan": "", "sub_type": "", "create_datetime": "20090511152102", "is_info_completed": "1", "pay_type": "2", "up_link": "", "promotion_code": "", "technology": "", "offer_id": "400001035", "dev_staff_id": "", "account_id": "", "deploy_accept_date": "", "serial": "8984049767000887694", "group_id": "", "ip_gateway": "", "first_connect": "", "org_product_code": "MIGRATE", "start_money": "100000", "keep_alive": "", "account": "" }' \
| kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -P -t subscriber
```

#### Stream output

Note the `null` in the second column - this is the key (the first column is the timestamp of the message; the remainder of the columns are the declared fields in the message)

```
ksql> select * from str_subscriber_json;
1528368689380 | null | 1083168000 |  | 10922428129 |  | 2 | 2046573688 | 452049760887694 | 8984049767000887694 | 2 | HPN03 | 400001035 | 000 | 20090511152847 | 20090511152102 |  | 0 | 0 | 1000405100 |  |  |  |  | 20090511152102 | TUDV_POPBGG | 20170801171355 | MIGRATE |  |  |  | MIGRATE |  | 100000 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 1 | 5131615 | null | null
```

#### Table output

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriber_json;
```

(No output)

### Test 2 - with a key set

The key is set arbitrarily here to `1`, using `kafkacat`'s `-K` flag to specify `:` as the key/value separator.

```
$ echo '1:{ "ip_router": "", "ip_lan": "", "isdn": "2046573688", "end_datetime": "", "shop_code": "1000405100", "reg_type_id": "5131615", "contract_id": "", "update_datetime": "20170801171355", "project": "", "telecom_service_id": "2", "local_speed": "", "password": "", "price_plan": "", "vip": "", "local_price_plan": "", "sub_id": "1083168000", "sta_datetime": "20090511152847", "update_number_1": "1", "act_status": "000", "network_class": "", "limit_usage": "", "num_reset_zone": "", "deposit": "", "create_user": "TUDV_POPBGG", "num_of_computer": "", "cust_id": "10922428129", "status": "2", "active_datetime": "20090511152102", "ip_view": "", "channel_type_id": "", "ip_wan": "", "imsi": "452049760887694", "infrastructure_type": "", "product_code": "HPN03", "expire_datetime": "", "speed": "", "private_ip": "", "update_user": "MIGRATE", "ip_static": "", "vlan": "", "sub_type": "", "create_datetime": "20090511152102", "is_info_completed": "1", "pay_type": "2", "up_link": "", "promotion_code": "", "technology": "", "offer_id": "400001035", "dev_staff_id": "", "account_id": "", "deploy_accept_date": "", "serial": "8984049767000887694", "group_id": "", "ip_gateway": "", "first_connect": "", "org_product_code": "MIGRATE", "start_money": "100000", "keep_alive": "", "account": "" }' \
| kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -P -t subscriber -K:
```

#### Stream output

Note the `1` in the second column - this is the key (the first column is the timestamp of the message; the remainder of the columns are the declared fields in the message)

```
1528368781916 | 1 | 1083168000 |  | 10922428129 |  | 2 | 2046573688 | 452049760887694 | 8984049767000887694 | 2 | HPN03 | 400001035 | 000 | 20090511152847 | 20090511152102 |  | 0 | 0 | 1000405100 |  |  |  |  | 20090511152102 | TUDV_POPBGG | 20170801171355 | MIGRATE |  |  |  | MIGRATE |  | 100000 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 1 | 5131615 | null | null
```

#### Table output

```
1528368781916 | 1 | 1083168000 |  | 10922428129 |  | 2 | 2046573688 | 452049760887694 | 8984049767000887694 | 2 | HPN03 | 400001035 | 000 | 20090511152847 | 20090511152102 |  | 0 | 0 | 1000405100 |  |  |  |  | 20090511152102 | TUDV_POPBGG | 20170801171355 | MIGRATE |  |  |  | MIGRATE |  | 100000 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 1 | 5131615 | null | null
```

### Rekeying topics automagically with KSQL

You can use KSQL to repartition topics. For example, taking your source `subscriber` topic, here is how to repartition it using KSQL in order to set the key:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM SUBSCRIBER_KEYED AS SELECT * FROM str_subscriber_json PARTITION BY sub_id;

 Message
----------------------------
 Stream created and running
----------------------------
ksql>
```

This populates a Kafka topic (`SUBSCRIBER_KEYED`) on which you can then define a table:

```
CREATE TABLE subscriber_table (sub_id VARCHAR,contract_id VARCHAR,cust_id VARCHAR,account_id VARCHAR,telecom_service_id VARCHAR,isdn VARCHAR,imsi VARCHAR,serial VARCHAR,status VARCHAR,product_code VARCHAR,offer_id VARCHAR,act_status VARCHAR,sta_datetime BIGINT,active_datetime BIGINT,sub_type VARCHAR,end_datetime BIGINT,expire_datetime BIGINT,shop_code VARCHAR,dev_staff_id VARCHAR,promotion_code VARCHAR,vip VARCHAR,account VARCHAR,create_datetime BIGINT,create_user VARCHAR,update_datetime BIGINT,update_user VARCHAR,deposit VARCHAR,limit_usage VARCHAR,password VARCHAR,org_product_code VARCHAR,num_reset_zone VARCHAR,start_money VARCHAR,is_info_completed VARCHAR,channel_type_id VARCHAR,first_connect VARCHAR,speed VARCHAR,keep_alive VARCHAR,price_plan VARCHAR,local_price_plan VARCHAR,project VARCHAR,local_speed VARCHAR,technology VARCHAR,network_class VARCHAR,infrastructure_type VARCHAR,deploy_accept_date BIGINT,group_id VARCHAR,ip_static VARCHAR,ip_view VARCHAR,ip_lan VARCHAR,ip_wan VARCHAR,ip_gateway VARCHAR,ip_router VARCHAR,num_of_computer VARCHAR,vlan VARCHAR,up_link VARCHAR,private_ip VARCHAR,pay_type VARCHAR,update_number_1 VARCHAR,reg_type_id VARCHAR,type VARCHAR,update_number VARCHAR) \
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='SUBSCRIBER_KEYED', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', KEY = 'sub_id' );
```

Now when you send a message to `subscriber`, even if it's not keyed, the table will work:

```
ksql> select * from subscriber_table;
1528369407576 | 1083168000 | 1083168000 |  | 10922428129 |  | 2 | 2046573688 | 452049760887694 | 8984049767000887694 | 2 | HPN03 | 400001035 | 000 | 20090511152847 | 20090511152102 |  | 0 | 0 | 1000405100 |  |  |  |  | 20090511152102 | TUDV_POPBGG | 20170801171355 | MIGRATE |  |  |  | MIGRATE |  | 100000 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 1 | 5131615 | null | null
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :)

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as answered - it'll help other people find it in the future. Thanks.

Comment: A little update would be better, we can't give the key in WITH() clause now. We have to give the primary key while declaring the columns for the table like: create table sub_table(sub_id varchar primary key, ...) with(...).