# Ksql, GROUP BY return ServerError:java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am using confluent 4.1.1 , I tried several aggregate commands, but always return NPE with GROUP BY:

```
ksql> select cust_id, count(*) as sum_sub from TBL_SUBSCRIBER GROUP BY cust_id;
 ServerError:java.lang.NullPointerException
ksql> 

ksql> describe extended TBL_SUBSCRIBER;

Type                 : TABLE
Key field            : SUB_ID
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Key format           : STRING
Value format         : DELIMITED
Kafka output topic   : subscriber (partitions: 10, replication: 3)

 Field               | Type                      
 ROWTIME             | BIGINT           (system) 
 ROWKEY              | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system) 
 SUB_ID              | VARCHAR(STRING)           
 CONTRACT_ID         | VARCHAR(STRING)           
 CUST_ID             | VARCHAR(STRING)           
 ACCOUNT_ID          | VARCHAR(STRING)           
 TELECOM_SERVICE_ID  | VARCHAR(STRING)
```

Please help me!

Comment: Using the same topic & stream/table definitions as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737222/ksql-select-on-table-not-show-anything/50739615#50739615), I got no error, so this *should* work :) Out of interest, can you try the latest [preview release of KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/preview-release) and see if it works there? If not, raise it as a [github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new) with steps to reproduce.

Comment: I tried with stream with same schema got no error, but with table , i got above error. Maybe the query only work for stream?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If this can be recreated on the latest version of ksqlDB then please raise a [Github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to see you've run into an issue with KSQL. Sounds like a bug in the old version you're running. I'm confident the issue you've run into has been fixed in more recent versions of ksqlDB.  I'm confident because there are explicit test cases that cover performing such a group by on a TABLE source: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/964c8ad665599123ad3635a2f806cb316e4f206e/ksqldb-functional-tests/src/test/resources/query-validation-tests/group-by.json#L184-L218

Please upgrade and retry.